# Why is MutableLiveData observer called only once when setValue() is called more than once?

Tags: android, android-livedata

Mutable LiveData in a `ViewModel`:

```
val viewStateLiveData: MutableLiveData<SomeViewState> = MutableLiveData()
```

When a network call fails, this function (in the `ViewModel`) is called from the main thread to update the view state object (to display a Snackbar, but then reset the state so it isn't re-displayed):

```
@UiThread
private fun onFailure() {
    viewStateLiveData.value = viewStateLiveData.value?.copy(retrievalSuccess = false, showProgress = false)
    viewStateLiveData.value = viewStateLiveData.value?.copy(retrievalSuccess = null)
}
```

The Fragment observes the `MutableLiveData`:

```
    viewModel.viewStateLiveData.observe(this,  Observer { viewState ->
        Timber.i("Update ViewState: $viewState")
    })
```

But the output is this single observer call (representing the second mutation):

```
Update ViewState: ViewState(retrievalSuccess=null, showProgress=false)
```

Rather than what I would expect, which would be two calls to the observer, reflecting both mutations:

```
Update ViewState: ViewState(retrievalSuccess=false, showProgress=false)
Update ViewState: ViewState(retrievalSuccess=null, showProgress=false)
```

Why is `MutableLiveData.setValue()` not triggering the observer after both mutations? The docs say "Sets the value. If there are active observers, the value will be dispatched to them." but it's hard not to conclude that this is not the case as setValue() is being called, but the observer (which is active) is not being triggered. The observer is definitely set up in advance of the `MutableLiveData` mutations.

I experimented with a series of mutations, and only ever see one call to the observer, which receives a view state object that combines all the prior mutations. So the calls to `setValue()` are mutating the view state, but only the last call in a series is triggering the observer.

I tried using `postValue()` in vain. Oddly, this behavior I'm describing was not present until recently, but it's not clear what has changed that has caused these issues.

Comment: Which version of android.arch.lifecycle are you using?

Comment: androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0

Comment: is your observer in active state when new values are set ?

Answer (score 0):

This was a Fragment lifecycle/timing issue, and ultimately caused by the ViewState mutations happening before the Fragment was in the active state, and so the LiveData just received a single event when the Fragment reached the Active, representing all mutations up to that point in a single initial event.

To fix it these changes were made:

`onCreate()` - create ViewModel

`onViewCreated()` - start observing the LiveData

`onResume()` / onStart() - make the network request (which starts the flow of mutated view states)

In debugging this issue it was really helpful to add logging to this, to see what state the Fragment was in: `fragmentManager?.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(...)`